# how to bind data to Layer.on in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have the following :

```
onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
        console.log(this) // context is here(containing all needed f() & variables 
        layer.on({
            click: function(e){

                }
         })
 }
```

I want to access the this context inside the click event click. I tried to bind(this) with layer.on.bind(this) but didn't work. So comes my question how can access to value stored in the higher context.

Answer (score 2):

`.bind()` applies to a function, even an anonymous one, so:

```
L.geoJson(data, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
    layer.on({
      click: (function(ev){
        // Whatever
      }).bind(this)
    })
  }
});
```

This defines an anonymous function`(function(ev) {...})`, then gets its closure by doing `(function(ev) {...}).bind(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

The 'this' context is a feature. Upon a click event e.target will hold a layer and in order to get the feature you can access `e.target.feature` inside your click function. No need to bind in my opinion.

```
onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
        console.log(this) // context is here(containing all needed f() & variables 
        layer.on({
            click: function(e){
                    var clicked_layer = e.target;
                    var clicked_feature = e.target.feature;
                }
         })
 }
```